# insmod error, invalid module format, fedora 35

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, insmod

I'm attempting to learn about kernel modules and followed along with a simple hello world example. My computer is running fedora 35. When I run `sudo insmod mymodule.ko` i get the error `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mymodule.ko: Invalid module format`.

From reading other peoples issues it seems to do with the kernel version being mismatched with what the module was compiled for, however `uname -r` returns `5.16.18-200.fc35.x86_64` and `modinfo mymodule.ko` gives `vermagic: 5.16.18-200.fc35.x86_64 SMP preempt mod_unload` which seems to suggest they are the same.

Following some other posts I tried dmesg and got:
`[ 1689.372354] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000d2334323, val ffffffffc140e000` which is quite different to what other users were experiencing (and doesn't seem to relate to kernel version), however I cannot make sense of it.

My makefile, in case it is useful:

```
obj-m += mymodule.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: The stock Fedora kernel requires modules to be signed.  Is yours?

Comment: I haven't actively done anything to sign it, just make and insmod mymodule.ko, how would I go about signing it?

Comment: it's not about signing, try re-install the headers, helped here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746914/linux-kernel-module-development-module-x86-modules-skipping-invalid-relocatio?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post set me on the right path and might help others not using fedora
[Linux Kernel Module Development "module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746914/linux-kernel-module-development-module-x86-modules-skipping-invalid-relocatio?noredirect=1)

The issue was with the kernel headers, as always the problem was solved with the reliable uninstall and reinstall:

```
sudo dnf remove kernel-devel
sudo dnf install kernel-devel
```

Comment: Yes, after removing and reinstalling `kernel-devel` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem we could resort to the ***--force-vermagic*** option, but this solution is potentially unsafe

```
sudo insmod mymodule.ko --force-vermagic
```